# Next Nearest Number Divisible By X

Tags: c#

What I want to do essentially, is take any number a user has input, and round it to the next closest whole number divisible by X, excluding 1.

IE (X = 300):

> Input = 1 Output = 300
>
> Input = 500 Output = 600
>
> Input = 841 Output = 900
>
> Input = 305 Output = 300

Comment: Your last example contradicts your stated requirement.

Comment: Shouldn't 305 result in 600? Your question says 'next largest number'.

Answer (score 22):

Just (integer) divide by X, add one, then multiply by X.

```
int output = ((input / x) + 1) * x;
```

Comment: Now it doesn't work for e.g. 300

Comment: This rounds 305 to 600, not 300.

Comment: Bleh, I just took note of which ^

Comment: Ah, yeah - I didn't notice your question was edited to say "closest".

Comment: Regardless, this much is well enough to work off of.
Thank you, truly.

Comment: Not only helpful for c#, thanks @Blorgbeard

Comment: Just used this to build something like a `cron` scheduler. It takes the current datetime as an integer number of seconds since the epoch time, and an interval (i.e. every 5 minutes, or 10 days, or whatever) as an integer number of seconds, and it then very easily calculates the next time, as an integer number of seconds, something should be run. Your answer made this scheduling functionality trivial to implement.

Comment: For input == x it returns 2 * x which is wrong. It should be a slightly modified version of a chunking algorithm to solve this problem: ((input + x - 1) / x) * x  <<all on integer division>>

Answer (score 5):

Based on your example behaviour I would do something like this:

```
double GetNearestWholeMultiple(double input, double X)
    {
      var output = Math.Round(input/X);
      if (output == 0 && input > 0) output += 1;
      output *= X;

      return output;
    }
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer